# Advanced Custom Field: How to show data in custom page?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Now I have a problem situation with Advanced Custom Field plugin in Wordpress.

Every posts with different information in Advanced Custom Field (ACF), for examples:

```
-post #1: los angeles

-post #2: texas

-post #3: california
```

Now, I want to create a custom page named 'Show Locations' template for showing that relevant information when use click on a certain link. How can I track a link that user click on and show relevant data for them.

I've tried:

```
<?php get_field('field_name', $post->ID); ?>
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: You create page for each location in the template 'Show Locations'? and you set the ACF in each page?

Answer (score 1):

To record user interactivity you will need to use javascript and send the data back to the server. PHP is a server-side language so you cannot do it only by using PHP.

E.g

```
<div data-field-id="1" onClick="sendIdToServer(1)">Texas</div>
```

You will need to implement a JS method called 'sendIdToServer'

```
function sendIdToServer(id) {
   .. //Read JQuery docs for $.ajax or $.post
}
```